# toggle off caps lock with shift key on windows 11

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, capslock, modifier-keys

On my old computer, when <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> is activated and I press the <kbd>shift</kbd> key, it disables the caps look.

On my new computer under windows 11, when <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> is activated and I keep the <kbd>shift</kbd> key pressed, it inserts lowercase letters but when I release it, <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> remains activated.

How to get the old behavior (press <kbd>shift</kbd> turn off <kbd>caps-lock</kbd>) on windows 11

Remark: I use french layout where this behavior is suposed to be default https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_Lock#Behavior

Comment: It was the old computer which displayed non-standard behaviour. Perhaps it had some device-specific control panel to allow this mode.

Comment: @Tetsujin Not in french layout (see my edit)

Comment: @Yukulélé You may have had that behavior on a computer in the past, but I've never heard of it. And I happen to have several French colleagues visiting today at the office. I asked them. Their computers don't have this behavior (Windows 10). CAPS LOCK doesn't auto-cancel when SHIFT is pressed. And they all say they never heard of that being standard.  And that Wikipedia page you linked too describes something ELSE: CAPS LOCK affecting non-alphabet keys, which doesn't have anything to do with cancel-CAPS-mode behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done just like under, or at least close to, win 10.

- Open "Settings" and navigate as follows
- Time & language
- Typing
- Advanced keyboard settings
- Input language hot keys".

This should open a window called "Text Services and Input Languages" it should contain an "Advanced Key Settings" section where you can switch between the two modes of how to turn off Caps Lock.
I find that a lot more comfortable as well and is usually one of the first things I change when setting up my profile after a fresh windows installation.

Answer (score 0):

> On my old computer, when caps-lock is activated and I press the shift
> key, it disables the caps look.

That is most likely a function of BIOS in the old computer and is not standard behavior on any computer I have (or have had).

So you will need to use the Caps Lock key to both toggle Caps ON and then OFF. -  This is quite normal.

Comment: Not in french layout (see my edit)

Comment: Even French still uses Caps Lock as a toggle

Comment: I have a French keyboard here (English box, French keyboard, packaging error). Caps Lock works the same.